# How to resolve different table name in laravel insert?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why the table name is different.

I create table name is tb_user (model - Tb_user)

How to resolve different table name?

[image]

```
use App\Models\Tb_user;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

...

```
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
       
        $now = now();


        //insert data        
        $user = new Tb_user;
        $user->id = $request->user_id;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->user_pw);  
        $user->name = $request->user_nm;      
        $user->phone = $request->user_tel;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->grade = '5';        
        $user->join_dt = $now;
        $register = $user->save();
```

Comment: How did you create that table? Usually, Laravel resolves the table names automatically, and if you created that table through Laravels tooling, it should receive the proper name

Comment: I made by artisan make:model

Comment: if your real table is `users` then add `protected $table = 'users';` to your tb_user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should follow Laravel naming conventions. Here are a few examples:

**Tables:** posts, comments, comment_post

**Columns:** id, post_id, comment_id

**Controllers:** PhotoController, TaskController

**Models:** Page, Card, Post

**Alternatively** we can spacify the name of the table in the model class. to do that add following to the model `tb_user`

```
protected $table = 'tb_user';
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the table related to **Tb_user** model.

In laravel you can do this by editing the **Tb_user** model and adding

```
protected $table = 'tb_user';
```

In this way laravel will not try to find the table name automatically but will fetch it from the property.

**FYI:**

Laravel has conventions on model name and database table names.

Quoted from Laravel Documentation:

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used
> as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in
> this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the
> flights table, while an AirTrafficController model would store records
> in an air_traffic_controllers table.

Link to official Laravel Documentation pointing naming conventions: [Laravel Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)